Replacing numbers with numbers in R?
I just have what seems like a simple list of numbers, that I'd like to recategorize.
The numbers are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
I'd like to recode such that 1,2 = 1, 5=2 and 3,4,6,7 = 3.
I've tried the following without luck:
df %>% mutate(var=recode(var, '1'='1', '2'='1', '3'='3', '4'='3', '5'='2', '6'='3', '7'='3'))
recode(df$var, `1` = 1, `2` = 1, `5` = 2, `3` = 3, `4` = 3, `6` = 3, `7` = 3)

Any tips?
Thanks!
Please see above- Mutate, recode.

use indexing var <- 1:7; c(1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3)[var] or factors factor(var, 1:7, c(1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3))

You could use case_when:
library('tidyverse')

set.seed(06192024)

numbers <- sample(1:7, size = 100, replace = TRUE)

table(numbers)

Returns:
numbers
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
18  8  6 15 21 20 12 

While:
numbers_recoded <- case_when(
  numbers == 1 | numbers == 2 ~ 1,
  numbers == 5 ~ 2,
  numbers == 3 | numbers == 4 | numbers == 6 | numbers == 7 ~ 3
)

table(numbers_recoded)

Returns:
numbers_recoded
 1  2  3 
26 21 53 


You can use %in% to shorten the code.

case_match might be simpler too, since all the tests are against ‘numbers’.
